# Check whether +[UIImage imageNamed:] found an image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I have an long if statement to decide what image to show in a `UIImageView`. They are all .png files, and I use the code:

```
if (whatever) {
    image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"imageName.png"];
}
```

Does anyone know of a way to check to see if the program can find the image? So that if the image does not exist in the program, it can display an error image or something?

Comment: The image should be stored on file? If yes, this is not the way to check, `[UIImage imageNamed]` should be used only for bundle files.

Comment: Very good comment! But still, there might be cases when you fail to package the app correctly so it actually has bundled images missing ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
+[UIImage imageNamed:]
```

will return `nil` if it couldn't find a corresponding image file. So just check for that:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"];
if (image == nil)
{
    [self displayErrorMessage];
}
```

Comment: @W'rkncacnter Ah yes, sorry, I overlooked it. It's a class method, definitely.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest snippet would be

```
image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"] ? : [UIImage imageNamed:@"fallback_image"]
```

but do you really want such code?

Make another check:

```
if (whatever) {
    image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"imageName.png"];
    if(image == nil) {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"fallback_image"];
    }
}
```

it still can be shorted, like

```
if(! (image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"imageName.png"]) ) {
    ...
}
```

but you're toying with readability here.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest using a dictionary instead of a long `if`. You can key each image name by `whatever`. If `whatever` isn't currently an object, make an `enum` that will encapsulate that information and use `NSNumber`s to box the values of the enum.

Then, you can check for `nil` when you try to retrieve the image. `imageNamed:` uses `nil` to indicate failure, so:

```
if( !image ){
    // No image found
}
```